# Using Python OS module: Finding out which files in list of files are already in a specific folder

Tags: python

I have a folder that has hundreds of files in it. I have a list of files that I know need to be deleted, so I am trying to write code to figure out: which files in this list are in this folder, and which are not.

I am using the os module, and I know how to walk through all of the files in my folder using `os.walk`, but what I don't know is how to specify if the file is in my `files_list`.

So I want to check if the file name in my `files_list` is in "folder" and if it is, then append it to `bad_list`, and if it isn't then append it to `good_list`. This is what I have so far:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_path):
    for file in files:
        if file in folder:
            badlist.append(file)
        else:
            good_list.append(file)
```

My question is, how do I put in the "is in `files_list`" part of this? I assume it should go after the `if file in folder` part, to say something like "is in `files_list`" but I can't figure out exactly how to write that in the code.

I am new to Python, so apologies if this is very simple.

Comment: would it be possible to give a snip of your file structure? Also, I'm not sure what `folder` means in your code. You don't post where you declared it...

Comment: Hi, sorry, I can't give a snip of that at the moment, but I actually think I just figured out my own problem: where it says folder, I think that should be files_list, if that makes sense to you. Sorry for wasting your time with this!

Comment: What does `files_list` contain? Do you have full, absolute paths, relative paths (relative to what directory if so), or only the base filenames?

Comment: `files_list` contains the base filename, so 'xyz.csv' and so forth. Then the folder I am pointing to has the same thing. So essentially I just want to match if a filename in the `files_list` is also in that folder.

Comment: Then all you need to do is check if `file in files_list` is true. You may want to make `files_list` a *set* to make that test a lot faster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that makes sense. That is what I was missing, would you recommend doing `if file not in _files_list`?

Comment: @hapigolucki: you are sorting files into good and bad lists, it doesn't matter if you use `if file in files_list` or `if file not in files_list`, you are only swapping the two blocks for the two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just try to delete the files you know that are under the folder and ignore any error

```
import os

files_to_remove = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
folder_name = '/the_files_folder'
for file_to_remove in files_to_remove:
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(folder_name, file_to_remove))
    except OSError:
       pass
```

Comment: `except:` should be `except OSError:`. Imagine you have a typo in one variable name. Best answer so far, that said.

Comment: code was modified in order to catch OSError only

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for membership testing.

Assuming `folder` is a list of file names with extensions (e.g.`'foo.txt'`), make `folder` a set then use set methods to differentiate the files.  Use `os.path.join` if you want to store complete paths in the good and bad lists.

```
folder = set(folder)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_path):
    files = set(files)
    #badlist.extend(files.intersection(folder))
    for fname in files.intersection(folder):
        badlist.append(os.path.join(root, fname))
    #goodlist.extend(files.difference(folder))
    for fname in files.difference(folder):
        goodlist.append(os.path.join(root, fname))
```